# Работа с русcкими строками.Как узнать индекс одной из букв?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть строка, состоящая из цифр и букв русского алфавита. Нужно узнать индекс одной из букв.
При использовании `s.find('Н')` выдается ошибка.

Использую *python-2.7* под *Ubuntu*.

Answer (score 3):

```
s.find(u'Н')
```

Comment: Да я тоже так подумал сначала, но не помогло.

Comment: `isinstance(s, unicode)`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно перевести входные данные в unicode. и вызвать функцию find() передавая ей в качестве параметра unicode объект.

Можно посмотреть тут:
https://sites.google.com/site/whitedjango/home/pythonilidjangoproblemaskodirovkoj

Answer (score 1):

```
string = u'АБВ123'
string.find(u'Б')
1
```